# Must I creat a class attributes to get the input of TextCtrl, can it be local?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxwidgets, wxpython

Here is the original code, where I created a `wx.TextCtrl` attributes `self.tc1`, the binding event works fine:

```
import wx


class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, title):
        super().__init__(None, title=title)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.tc1 = None
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(2, 2)
        self.set_name(sizer)
        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        sizer.Fit(self)

    def set_name(self, sizer):
        text1 = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Enter your name:")
        sizer.Add(text1, pos=(0, 0), flag=wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.BOTTOM, border=10)
        self.tc1 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, style=wx.TE_CENTER, value="enter_name_here")
        self.tc1.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.on_get_text)
        sizer.Add(self.tc1, pos=(0, 1), flag=wx.TOP|wx.RIGHT|wx.BOTTOM|wx.EXPAND, border=5)

    def on_get_text(self, e):
        print(self.tc1.GetValue())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Example("Example").Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

What if I want to let the text control `self.tc1` to be local variable to the method `self.set_name`, because I don't want to pollute the class with too many attributes. To be clear, if I change the method `self.set_name` this way, making the `tc1` a local variable to that method:

```
def set_name(self, sizer):
    text1 = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Enter your name:")
    sizer.Add(text1, pos=(0, 0), flag=wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.BOTTOM, border=10)
    tc1 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, style=wx.TE_CENTER, value="enter_name_here")
    # tc1.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.on_get_text)
    sizer.Add(tc1, pos=(0, 1), flag=wx.TOP|wx.RIGHT|wx.BOTTOM|wx.EXPAND, border=5)
```

**How can I modify the Bind method to achieve the same effects?** I have too many widgets in the class, I really don't want to make every one of them a class attributes.

Comment: this variable is not a class attribute, rather a class member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the EVT_TEXT event that is passed to the handler holds a reference to the object that it's bound to. To get that object call [GetEventObject()](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.Event.html#wx.Event.GetEventObject)

```
def on_get_text(self, event):
    tc1 = event.GetEventObject()
    print(tc1.GetValue())
```

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I am looking for!

Comment: I have asked another similar question, please have a look if you have time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53817548/how-to-i-disable-the-text-ctrl-when-i-select-the-combo-box-to-a-particular-value